# Zend Http Client

Tags: api, zend-framework, linkedin-api, zend-http-client

While setting GET parameters for Zend_Http_Client, you can use array with name-value pairs or pass name and value on each call to the function setParameterGet.

While making a call to LinkedIn API, I have a situation where there are multiple GET parameters with the same name, different values.

e.g. http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/network/updates?type=STAT&type=PICT&count=50&start=50

The "type" parameter is repeated.

I have not been able to generate this uri using the Zend_Http_Client because the second "type" parameter's value override the first one.

Can anybody help me out how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In current implementation you can not have two or more parameters with the same name.
What you should do instead is construct client like this:

```
$client = new Zend_Http_Client ('http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/network/updates?type=STAT&type=PICT&count=50&start=50');
```

That way you will be able to overcome its limitation.

Comment: Are you sure it should work that way? I have tried setting the uri with query but it does not work.

Comment: Yes, I am sure. What version of ZF have you got?

Comment: 1.11 .. i'll debug again to see exactly why its not working. I'll post my find here:) ..tnx for the help thoguh

Comment: And remember, I tested the solution above only for Socket adapter. I suppose for Curl adapter it won't work.